# GAE post does not show directly after put

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a very simple "guestbook" script on GAE/Python. It often happens however, that entries which I put() into the datastore are not showing right away - I almost always need to refresh.

```
def post(self):

    t = NewsBase(
    date = datetime.now(),
    text = self.request.get('text'),
    title = self.request.get('title'),
    link = self.request.get('link'),
    upvotes = [],
    downvotes = [],
    )
    t.put()

    q = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM NewsBase ORDER BY date DESC')

    template_values = {
    'q' : q,
    'user' : user,
    'search' : search
    }
    template = jinja_environment.get_template('finaggnews.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

I'm sure there is a solution to this?

Best,
Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the eventual consistency model of HRD.

You should really read some of the intro docs, Structuring Data for Strong Consistency - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency  and do some searching of SO.  This question has been asked many times before.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's actually difficult to search for this, tried a few times... Thanks anyways

Comment: This might be a good starting point https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ I find it worth while having a look at all the docs for appengine on python from time to time.